# How can I make error messages in admin

Tags: errors, notifications

In my WP Plugin I have made an error handler. It works so far but I'd like to **not echo in admin_notices**, but have that nice little message box of wordpress if sth is going wrong:

[image: red box]

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the correct html markup, namely a paragraph `p` inside a container `div` with a certain class. Usable classes are `updated` green, `error` & `notice-error` red, `notice-warning` orange, `notice-info` blue. Exemplary usage:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse330943_admin_notices' );
function wpse330943_admin_notices() {
  <div class="notice notice-error">
    <p>
      //some text
    </p>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [admin_notices doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) they tell how to do so
I just found it...

Comment: The Settings API has some [functions for error handling](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/#function-reference) that can be used to generate messages.

Comment: @Nicolai It didn't work ... I may made sth wrong, but since this works out I won't try again now